# Insulator or conductor with different boundary conditions

Tags: conductors, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, insulators

I'm studying the 1-D SSH model. It's a toy model for a topological insulator. Here's the [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295) I'm using. If the hopping amplitudes $v$ and $w$ are equal, then with periodic boundary conditions we have a conductor. If however, we take open boundary conditions, a plot of the eigenvalues shows that there is a band gap with the same values of $v$ and $w$. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you refering to fig 1.4 in the paper you cite as evidence for  an enegy  gap at $u=v=1$?  If so, you need to realize that in the that plot the authors  are using a very small (10 site) system. The gaps between the eigenvalues are therefore due to the finite-size discreteness of the eigenvalues $E_n=\pm 2\cos k$ with $k$ something like $k=(n+1/2)\pi/N$ for $N$ sites. There will only be an exact zero energy $E=2 \cos \pi/2$ state when  $N$ is odd. $N=10$ is *even* in their plot.  As $N$ becomes larger the spaces between the $N=1$ eigenvalues  will fill in, and there will be no  gap at zero energy in the $u=v$ case.